# Warning file_get_contents () failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 402 Payment Required

Tags: php, curl, youtube

I got this error today but before that, my code was working fine.

The code is working fine on localhost but I get error on my website

Here is the line of code that produces the error:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?hl=en&video_id={$_GET['id']}&eurl=&el=detailpage&gl=US&ps=default");
```

and the error:

> **Warning**: file_get_contents(https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?hl=en&video_id=SD3S27fMGzc&eurl=&el=detailpage&gl=US&ps=default): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 402 Payment Required
>   in **/home/zyxs/public_html/site.com/vid/youtube.php** on line **2**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get youtube video title in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664482/get-youtube-video-title-in-php)

Comment: Probably because your trying to download something you need to pay for?

Comment: @Andre this code is working in my localhost but in my website its is showing error

Comment: @watcher  error is same but i did not understand how to fix it can you help me to fix this issue

Comment: @user2468472 without going over the whole set of answers there, try [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9664713/697370). If that fails, try rewording your question around trying to get that curl call to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function http_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  if (FALSE === ($retval = curl_exec($ch))) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
  } else {
    return $retval;
  }
}

$request_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SD3S27fMGzc';
$result = http_get_contents($request_url);

$simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

print_r($simpleXML);
```

Comment: i want to use this https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?hl=en&video_id={$_GET['id']}&eurl=&el=detailpage&gl=US&ps=default with curl how can i use it